# Set Line Width in XNA 4.0

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

Is there a way to set the line width for the `Line` primitive in XNA 4.0?

In OpenGL, the equivalent would be glLineWidth();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you will have to create two triangles per line to get it.

Here explain it to OpenGl users and offer a code solution:

http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2009/02/16/drawing-primitives-in-xna-from-a-vertex-buffer/

Comment: Ok. Thanks. It's not very cool with two triangles because I will have to apply some billboarding to them as I'm drawing the axes of my objects and I can rotate around them.